# Can a Flash object in the browser interact with a scanner

Tags: flash, air

I know Flash can work with my webcam. Is it possible for a Flash object in the browser to get a document scanned by a hardware scanner?

Will it be different if this will be an [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Flash object in the browser would not have this access directly.

Adobe AIR also cannot access a USB device directly in this fashion. http://forums.adobe.com/message/1038462

You may be able to achieve success by using Merapi (http://merapiproject.net/) with Adobe AIR and Java combined.